# How to update one table from another table based on joins and subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have two tables. I want to update one with another.
I have written two queries to show you the result. Here are my two queries

```
 select PrjTermsID,InstNo,InstDesc,BlockID from ProjectPaymentTerms where BlockID=1
```

`select PlotBookingID,InstNo,InstDesc,PrjTermsID from PlotPaymentTerms where PlotBookingID in
 ( select PlotBookingID from PlotBooking where PlotID in (  select PlotID from PlotMaster where AppartmentBlock=1))`

and see the image for results [image]

First table has 1 to 13 records with InstNo and second table has each PlotBookingID has 13 records.(Each plot will have 13(all) payment terms right?). Now I want to update the second table `PlotPaymentTerms` with first table autogenerated Id. IF I try with Inner join it is giving more results. How can I write update query to update the second table?

Comment: why are you updating the id's in the second table ?

Comment: before were not adding PrjTermsID in second table. Now we added that thing in my application. So past records are empty as I have added that field recentry in second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update ppt
set ppt.PrjTermsID  = pp.PrjTermsID
from PlotPaymentTerms ppt
inner join ProjectPaymentTerms pp on ppt.InstNo = pp.InstNo and ppt.BlockID = 1
inner join PlotBooking pb on ppt.PlotBookingID = pb.PlotBookingID 
inner join PlotMaster pm on pb.PlotID = pm.PlotID 
where pm.AppartmentBlock = 1
```

please check this.

Comment: It has updated with wrong ids :( . I think we should not use INNER JOIN. It is updated like alternate rows with right IDs. like 1, 3, 5, 7, 9... are right. and evens ids are inserted wrong

Comment: @Iam can you please check with above query now, I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the right way to do. Anyways it works for me.

```
update ppt set ppt.PrjTermsID  = pp.PrjTermsID from PlotPaymentTerms ppt
inner join ProjectPaymentTerms pp on ppt.InstNo = pp.InstNo and pp.BlockID=1
and ppt.PlotBookingID in(select PlotBookingID from PlotBooking where PlotID in (  select PlotID from PlotMaster where AppartmentBlock=1))
```

Thnaks to @Mukund

Comment: inner join is always better than the in clause. it executes fast. I don't understand how it's not updated even number rows. If it's working for odd then it should work for even too, b/c logic is same. @Iam